# Specific file type allowed? php upload

Tags: php, html

Im creating a image uploader, and i dont know how to do so only the filetype can be .jpg so im asking you, do you know it?

heres what i got so far:

```
    <?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['username']) {
    $target_path = "users/$username/";

    $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
        "has been uploaded";
        header("Location: user.php");
    } else{
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
}
    else {
            echo "Only members can be here. Register <a href='index.php'>here</a>";
  }
  ?>
```

And one more thing, how may i rename the uploaded file to : "profile.jpg" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some important things to consider here:

First of all, never rely on the file extension that was provided. I could upload a php file with the extension `.jpg` if I wanted. Granted, I'd probably have to do some more to actually get it to execute as a php file on your server, but it certainly was not a valid image.

If the upload was successful, `$_FILES[ 'uploadedfile' ][ 'type' ]` will hold the mime-type that was provided by the request. However, this should also not be trusted, as this can be tampered with as well.

A more reliable way to determine whether the uploaded file is actually an image of type jpeg is to use the function `getimagesize`. `getimagesize()` will return false if it's not a valid image and will return an array with information about the image, if it recognized the file as an image. Index `2` of the array will hold a value that corresponds with [one of these constants](http://php.net/manual/en/image.constants.php) that begin with `IMAGETYPE_`.

```
$info = getimagesize( $_FILES[ 'uploadedfile' ]['tmp_name'] );
if( $info !== false )
{
    // file is an image to begin with

    if( $info[ 2 ] == IMAGETYPE_JPEG )
    {
        // file appears to be a valid jpeg image
    }
}
```

This is somewhat of an old school method which, as far as I know, is reliable though.

I believe, depending on platform (Windows/*nix) and version (< 5.3, >= 5.3) there are more reliable ways to determine the actual mime-type of a file though. I'll see what I can find for you about that later on.

**edit:**
I forgot about the renaming part.

Simply replace this:

```
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
```

... with this:

```
$target_path = $target_path . 'profile.jpg';
```

In other words, when you move the file with `move_uploaded_file()` the second argument will be the new path (including the new file name).

Comment: How do i rename the uploaded file?

Comment: To the downvoter: would you mind telling me what is wrong with this answer, so I can improve it? Just about [every answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281143/best-way-to-get-a-photos-file-extension-type-in-php) seems to agree with this answer.

Answer (score 2):

The jpeg magic number is 0xffd8 so you could check that the first two bytes of the file are 0xff and 0xd8 and if they are not then it is certainly not a jpeg.

Example:

```
$fp = fopen($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], 'rb');
$bytes = fread($fp, 2);

if (ord($bytes{0}) != 0xff && ord($bytes{1}) != 0xd8) {
    echo "Not JPEG!";
} else {
    echo "It is JPEG";
}
```

A truly malicious user will attempt to upload a file by bypassing your form altogether which would allow them to upload a file of any type, give it a .jpg extension even though it is not, send the image/jpg|jpeg mime type even though that is not the correct mime type because the browser just sends that mime type as a service to you, but it cannot be trusted.

Answer (score 1):

HTML5's [accept](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#file-upload-state) attribute allows you to specify what types of file your input will accept:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/jpeg" />
```

This means the file selection dialog that appears will only allow you to select jpegs. I've no idea about how well this is supported in browsers though.

**Edit:** I also have no idea how the browsers will perform this check. If you **really want to enforce the jpeg only policy**, then you'll need something like what @drew010 has proposed.

Comment: +1 because I use it too (for a graceful degradation javascript snipplet that uses the attribute to add a filter when the file api is available, in addition of server filtering of course), however afaik it's [not (yet) supported properly by any browser according to w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp).

Comment: -1 This is never reliable of course, as this can easily be bypassed. Always check input on the server. This is just a convenience method for the user.

Comment: That's why I said you would also want a server side check. As for it being "just a convenience", I like to make sure things are convenient and intuitive for users of any app I create.

Comment: @JohnKeyes: I must have overlooked that statement. And I agree with your sentiment about convenience and intuitiveness of course. I'll retract my down-vote. (You'll have to edit your answer though, for me to retract it, as it has been to long since I voted, to retract it.)

Comment: @fireeyedboy I've emphasized the server-side check in my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) to verify an image's format.

However, securing file uploads is very complex, and additional steps are required. For example, it's dangerous to use the user provided original file name.

See this question for advanced discussion about the things that can/need to be done to achieve a really high level of security:

[PHP image upload security approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317083/php-image-upload-security-approach)

Answer (score 1):

There are different checks you can do to allow only JPG images, according to the level of safety you want to achieve.

Simply, you can check for the *jpg extension, but that would be quite naive, as if a file is renamed it will trick your code.
Another way could be checking against the MIME type (jpeg or pjpeg), which is part of the $_FILES array

```
$_FILES['uploadedfile']['type']
```

but this information is not reliable and can be spoofed.

**But the best solution** that comes to my mind is to use the function [getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php), which analizes the images and you can get several information, the most important being to validate the file being actually a real image.
This function returns array with 7 elements.

```
Index 0 and 1 contains the width and the height of the image.
Index 2 is one of the IMAGETYPE_XXX constants indicating the type of the image.

Index 3 is a text string with the correct height="yyy" width="xxx" string 
*mime* is the correspondant MIME type of the image.
*channels* will be 3 for RGB pictures and 4 for CMYK pictures.
*bits* is the number of bits for each color.
```

The above info are taken from the manual page.

Comment: +1 LOL, this is [just about the exact same answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616994/specific-file-type-allowed-php-upload/7617138#7617138) I already provided to OP in an earlier question of him, which is an exact duplicate of this question. :D

Comment: @fireeyedboy oh god, I'm sorry, I didn't know that he already asked the same question..and that you provided a similar (well, much better) answer!

Comment: No need to apologize at all, I didn't expect you to know about it. I just found it amusing to see OP get answered about the exact same answer twice to two exact same questions of OP. :) In other words: good answer! :D

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot you can do, to make picture upload more safe:

- Resize the images to a standard size. This makes sure that malicious code within an uploaded picture will be scrambled up.
- Rename the uploaded picture to a uniform name schema, that makes it harder to request a prepared file and you can ensure the correct file extension.
- Do some settings in your .htaccess file, so only jpg files will be delivered from the picture directory.

Here an example of how to write a .htaccess file:

```
IndexIgnore *
Deny from all

<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg)$">
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

These are some points i think are important, but the list is of course not conlusive.