# How to restrict uploading of duplicate file extension in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a Problem in "PHP/pgSQL". Suppose there is a uploading field in php, which only accepts ".pdf" files. But, if i renamed a 'jpg/image' file such as "bird.jpg" to "bird.pdf" then it also uploaded to the folder. My requirement is not to upload these kinda duplicate renamed files to server. I have tried possible ways by htaccess and php codes. But can't get any result. Please Help me soon. Thanx in Advance. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Specific file type allowed? php upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616994/specific-file-type-allowed-php-upload)

Answer (score 0):

never trust the file extension:

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['file']['TMP_NAME']);

if ($mime !='application/pdf'){
//BAD FILE
}
```

ref: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php